# "Unable to get the Slope property of the WorksheetFunction class " Error

Tags: excel, vba

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCmvB.png)

```
Sub GraphData()
Dim GraphStart As Integer
Dim GraphEnd As Integer
Dim TimeRange As Range
Dim AssayRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim AssayTime As Date
Dim k As Integer
Dim m As Integer

LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Range("B15").Value + 17

For k = 18 To LastRow
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Range("H" & k).Value < 2 Then
       GraphStart = k + 1
    End If
Next

For m = 18 To LastRow
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Range("H" & m).Value < 32 Then
        GraphEnd = m
    End If
Next

Set TimeRange = Application.Range(Cells(GraphStart, "F"), Cells(GraphEnd, "F"))
Set AssayRange = Application.Range(Cells(GraphStart, "H"), Cells(GraphEnd, "H"))


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Assay Result").Range("D31").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(AssayRange, TimeRange)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Assay Result").Range("D32").Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Correl(AssayRange, TimeRange)) ^ 2

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Assay Result").Range("D33").Value = Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(AssayRange), 2) & " to " & Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(AssayRange), 2)

End Sub
```

I believe that someone have this problem before. The error is inconsistant, occurs sometime.

1. The data range for calculating slope is changing. So I set up two data range variables for the x and y serie: TimeRange and AssayRange
2. The TimeRange data are from column F18 to the end of F column and the Assay Range are from column H18 to the end of H.
3. Only the data in H column >2 and <32 will be select into ranges and used for calculation.
4. The data in column F and H are decimal data type.
   Any ideas of where the error is from?

Comment: Your code is hard to understand. I think I need to explain the intent with the data on the sheet.

Comment: This data is from the measurement of a reaction. A measurement was recorded every 5 second. The recorded values were converted to product concentrations in column H. The elapse times were  calculated on column F. Data is from column 18. From previous step, I calculated row numbers of the data on cell B15, which is used to calulate LastRow .

Comment: I don't know where to add a pic. Can someone help?

Comment: use help. There introduce method to add pic.

Comment: Thanks Dy.Lee. The picture is loaded. Please "Table" on the top. It is a screenshot of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub GraphData()
Dim GraphStart As Integer
Dim GraphEnd As Integer
Dim TimeRange As Range
Dim AssayRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim AssayTime As Date
Dim k As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction

Set Wf = WorksheetFunction
Set Ws = Worksheets("RawData")
Set toWs = Worksheets("Assay Result")

    With Ws
        LastRow = .Range("B15").Value + 17

        For k = 18 To LastRow
            If .Range("H" & k).Value < 2 Then
               GraphStart = k + 1
            End If
        Next
        For m = 18 To LastRow
            If .Range("H" & m).Value < 32 Then
                GraphEnd = m
            End If
        Next

        Set TimeRange = .Range("F" & GraphStart, "F" & GraphEnd)
        Set AssayRange = TimeRange.Offset(, 2)
    End With
    With toWs
        .Range("d31") = Wf.Slope(AssayRange, TimeRange)
        .Range("d32") = Wf.Correl(AssayRange, TimeRange) ^ 2
        .Range("d33") = Round(Wf.Min(AssayRange), 2) & " to " & Round(Wf.Max(AssayRange), 2)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I will try to figure out what is wrong with my old coding.

Comment: Cells(GraphStart, "F") is incorrect.  It should be ws.Cells(GraphStart, "F")

Comment: I just see this. Thank you very much, Dy.Lee.